# Why are changes I make to my layout not happening?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-editor

I'm building a layout with ConstraintLayout in Android Studio 3.0 using the Layout Editor. Any changes I make are not being reflected when I run the app on the emulator. I don't think the problem is with the emulator. I've deleted the app manually from the settings. Blueprint and design seem to be working fine. But something is happening from packaging the app to launching it to the emulator. I've tried different emulators. I've removed ui components from the Layout editor but still the same layout pops up on the emulator when I run the app!I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try disabling the instant app

Comment: I haven't enabled instant app

Comment: Make sure that you are making changes to the right file. Post your layout file.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi thank you